# Django - Problem of including user in the group

Tags: python, django

I'm using [django-groups-manager.](https://github.com/vittoriozamboni/django-groups-manager)

In my project, the user can create a group when registering. After registering, the user can enter the group he created. I'm getting this error after registering. How can I solve this problem?

> TypeError at /accounts/register/
>
> 'Group' instance expected, got <-Group: Technology->

**views.py**

```
from groups_manager.models import Group, GroupType, Member

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        new_group_name = form.cleaned_data['new_group_name']
        new_group, created = Group.objects.update_or_create(name=new_group_name)
        user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name=new_group_name))
        user.save()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```

**problematic place in code:**

```
user.groups.add(Group.objects.get(name=new_group_name))
```

Comment: You are mixing two `Group` models: The `Group` model in Django's `contrib.auth.models` , and the one in `groups_manager.models`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Django_groups_manager  has 'django auth sync' feature. The created group is also added in the normal group. What kind of path do I have to follow?

Comment: yes the models are *synchronized*. But your `Group.objects.get(..)` query, will thus still retrieve the `groups_manager` `Group` model object, not its `django.contrib.auth` counterpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are here mixing two models with the same name: (1) the `Group` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, and (2) the `Group` model from `groups_manager.models`.

The `Group` object you thus add to `user.groups.add(..)` is a `Group` object of the second (2) variant. You can fix this by importing the `Group` model from the `django.contrib.auth.models` module, for example through a different name:

```
from groups_manager.models import Group, GroupType, Member
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group as AGroup

def register_view(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        new_group_name = form.cleaned_data['new_group_name']
        new_group, created = Group.objects.update_or_create(name=new_group_name)
        user.groups.add(AGroup.objects.get(name=new_group_name))
        user.save()
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        new_user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'accounts/form.html', {'form': form, 'title': 'Üye Ol'})
```